# Add class to a vector of another class with textures

Tags: c++, sfml

I'm trying to make a game based on snake game. I got basics on OOP in c++, but I just started to learn in SFML.

My problem is that in my snake some parts can't be seen, like on the picture below.
[image]

So "Body" is my base class. I want my snake to has each part made from different sub-class. It also means that each part is going to have different texture.

For now I've made first sub-class called "Ironman". The gap I marked on picture is a part made from that sub-class. Rest of the snake are parts from class "Body".

If my code would work in the "gap", there should be seen a texture, the same like in the middle of the picture (Iron man head).

Ironman head in the middle is just for test :) it shows how Ironman-part should look like.

Here's my code.

**main.cpp**

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include<vector>
#include"Body.h"
#include<iostream>
#include"Ironman.h"

int main()
{
int w_width = 1000, w_height = 700;
float x = w_width / 2.0, y = w_height / 2.0;
double speed = 2.5;

sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(w_width, w_height), "Snake practise");

sf::RectangleShape map;
map.setSize(sf::Vector2f(700, 500));
map.setOrigin(map.getSize().x / 2.0, map.getSize().y / 2.0);
map.setPosition(w_width / 2.0, w_height / 2.0);
map.setFillColor(sf::Color::White);

enum Direction { UP, DOWN, RIGHT, LEFT };

int direct = UP;


sf::Texture pTexture;
pTexture.setSmooth(false);
if (!pTexture.loadFromFile("image/cp_shield.png"))
    std::cerr << "Error texture!" << std::endl;

sf::Texture ironTexture;
if (!ironTexture.loadFromFile("image/ironman.png"))
    std::cerr << "Error ironman!" << std::endl;

std::vector<Body> snake;
Body head(pTexture, w_width, w_height);
snake.push_back(head);

Ironman glowa(ironTexture, w_width, w_height);


for (int i = 1; i < 500; i++) {

    if (i <= 32) {
        Ironman newIron(ironTexture, w_width, w_height);

        snake.push_back(newIron);
    }
    else {
        Body newPart(pTexture, w_width, w_height);

        snake.push_back(newPart);
    }
}

for (int i = 1; i < snake.size(); i++) {
    if (i % 16 != 0) {
        snake[i].makeTransparent();
    }
}

sf::View view;
view.setCenter(sf::Vector2f(0,0));
view.setSize(w_width, w_height);


while (window.isOpen())
{
    sf::Vector2f lastPosition(snake[0].getPosX(),snake[0].getPosY());

    sf::Event event;
    while (window.pollEvent(event))
    {
        if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
            window.close();
    }

    //textures
    if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Up) && snake[0].getDirection() != DOWN) {
        snake[0].setDirection(UP);
    }
    else if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Down) && snake[0].getDirection() != UP) {
        snake[0].setDirection(DOWN);
    }
    else if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Right) && snake[0].getDirection() != LEFT) {
        snake[0].setDirection(RIGHT);
    }
    else if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Left) && snake[0].getDirection() != RIGHT) {
        snake[0].setDirection(LEFT);
    }

    if (snake[0].getDirection() == UP) {
        snake[0].moveUp(speed);
    }
    else if (snake[0].getDirection() == DOWN) {
        snake[0].moveDown(speed);
    }
    else if (snake[0].getDirection() == LEFT) {
        snake[0].moveLeft(speed);
    }
    else if (snake[0].getDirection() == RIGHT) {
        snake[0].moveRight(speed);
    }

    view.setCenter(snake[0].getPosX(), snake[0].getPosY());


    //movement
    sf::Vector2f newPosition(lastPosition);

    for (int i = 1; i < snake.size(); i++) {
        sf::Vector2f lastPosition(snake[i].getPosX(), snake[i].getPosY());
        //lastPosition = snake[i].getPosition();
        snake[i].setPosX(newPosition.x,newPosition.y);
        newPosition = lastPosition;

    }

    window.clear();

    window.setView(view);

    window.draw(map);
    window.draw(glowa);

    for (auto itr : snake)
        window.draw(itr);
        //itr.drawBody(window);

    window.display();
}

return 0;
```

}

**Body.cpp**

```
#include"Body.h"

Body::Body(){

}

Body::Body(sf::Texture& imgPath, int wWidth, int wHeight) {
  _Sprite.setTexture(imgPath);
  _Sprite.setPosition(sf::Vector2f(wWidth / 2.0, wHeight / 2.0));
  _Sprite.setOrigin(imgPath.getSize().x / 2.0, imgPath.getSize().y / 2.0);
  _Sprite.setScale(0.025,0.025);
}

Body::~Body() {

}

void Body::draw(sf::RenderTarget& target, sf::RenderStates states)const {
  target.draw(_Sprite, states);
}

void Body::drawBody(sf::RenderWindow& window) {
  window.draw(_Sprite);
}

void Body::setDirection(int direct) {
  _direction = direct;
}

int Body::getDirection() {
  return _direction;
}

void Body::moveUp(double speed) {
  _Sprite.move(sf::Vector2f(0, -speed));
}

void Body::moveDown(double speed) {
  _Sprite.move(sf::Vector2f(0, speed));
}

void Body::moveLeft(double speed) {
  _Sprite.move(sf::Vector2f(-speed, 0));
}

void Body::moveRight(double speed) {
  _Sprite.move(sf::Vector2f(speed, 0));
}

void Body::setPosX(float x, float y) {
  _Sprite.setPosition(x, y);
}

float Body::getPosX() {
  return _Sprite.getPosition().x;
}

float Body::getPosY() {
  return _Sprite.getPosition().y;
}

void Body::makeTransparent() {
  _Sprite.setColor(sf::Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
}
```

**Ironman.cpp**

```
#include"Ironman.h"

Ironman::Ironman() {

}

Ironman::Ironman(sf::Texture& imgPath, int wWidth, int wHeight) {
  _Sprite.setTexture(imgPath);
  _Sprite.setPosition(sf::Vector2f(wWidth / 2.0, wHeight / 2.0));
  _Sprite.setOrigin(imgPath.getSize().x / 2.0, imgPath.getSize().y / 2.0);
  _Sprite.setScale(0.1, 0.1);
}

Ironman::~Ironman() {

}

void Ironman::draw(sf::RenderTarget& target, sf::RenderStates states)const {
  target.draw(_Sprite, states);
}
```

If it's needed I can add header files :)

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your headers...

I assume you are expecting to call the derived class member functions with polymorphism (the `virtual` keyword)? `virtual` function calls are only polymorphic when invoked through a *pointer* or a *reference* to the base class. Storing derived class objects by base class *value* [slices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing) the object, so it is, in fact, a base class object in that context.

You are storing your Body parts in a `std::vector<Body>`. When you `push_back` a `Body` object, this works. When you `push_back` a `IronMan` object only the `Body` part of that object ever gets stored in the vector. You probably want a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base>>`, assuming C++11 or newer. Or at a minimum, you want `std::vector<Base *>`, but then you have to do the lifetime management by hand.

Comment: Okay, so first I tried to change my `vector` to vector made with pointers. But I don't know how to go through problem with `window.draw(itr);` at the end of `main.cpp`. I changed it to `window->draw(itr);` but it says that `window` needs to be a pointer type...

Comment: You need to dereference the pointers: `window.draw(*itr);`. Note that `itr` is misleading since you're using the range-for loop; you don't get an iterator - you get the object.